# Ruby on rails find an associated objects which has another association too

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a three models, which organized this way:

```
class Task < AR::Base
  has_one :taskable

class Taskable
  belongs_to :task
  has_many :supplies

class Supply < AR::Base
  belongs_to :taskable
```

How can I fetch all tasks, which taskable has at least one supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a *join* query .

```
# To fetch all tasks, for which taskable has at least one supply
Task.joins(taskable: :supplies)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a join, but with an additional condition:

```
Task.joins(taskable: :supplies).where("supplies.id IS NOT NULL")
```